# OLEDB Database command builder update function not working - Visual Basic

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I am attempting to add a row to an access database with the Adapter.update() Function but I keep getting this error:

```
  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147217900
   HResult=-2147217900
  Message=Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
  Source=Microsoft JET Database Engine
   StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
   at test.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
InnerException:
```

I have three databases where I attempt to do this and one does not raise an error but the others do. I have tried to create new Databases but they still raise the error. All of the databases use the .mdb file exstension. Does anyone have an idea what might be happening?

Here is the code where I attempt to update the table

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim Connection As New OleDbConnection
Dim Adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim Table As New DataTable
Dim Command As OleDbCommandBuilder
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ethan\OneDrive\Documents\test3.mdb"
    Adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Things", Connection)
    Command = New OleDbCommandBuilder(Adapter)

    Adapter.Fill(Table)
    Dim NewRow As DataRow = Table.NewRow
    NewRow("thing") = "Grapes"
    NewRow("count") = 4
    Table.Rows.Add(NewRow)
    Adapter.Update(Table)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you didnt set the Update command: `Adapter.InsetCommand = Command.GetInsertCommand()`